# Trying to set telegram user photo

Tags: javascript, telegram

I am trying to upload a photo to my Telegram profile using the Telegram API, but I am experiencing an error when using the new API constructor. Specifically, I am getting the error message "Api is not a constructor." I have tried multiple different approaches, but have not been able to successfully upload the photo. I should note that I am trying to upload the photo to my user profile, not to the profile of a bot. I am hoping to find a solution to this issue, as I have been unable to find a solution despite trying many different things.

```
const {
    Api,
    TelegramClient,
    ChatAction,
    FileBox,
    InputFile
} = require('telegram-bot-api');
const fs = require('fs');

// Replace 'apiId' and 'apiHash' with your API ID and API hash
const apiId = ”my-api-Id”;
const apiHash = 'my-hash';

// Function to authenticate the account
async function authenticate() {
    // Replace 'phoneNumber' with your phone number
    const phoneNumber = '+1234567890';
    // Create a new API object
    const api = new Api(apiId, apiHash);

    // Invoke the auth.sendCode method to request a code
    const result = await api.auth.sendCode({
        phone_number: phoneNumber,
    });
    console.log(result); // Prints the result of the sendCode method call

    // Check if the result contains an error
    if (result.error) {
        console.error(result.error);
        return;
    }

    // Save the result to a file
    await fs.promises.writeFile('auth.json', JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log('Auth result saved to auth.json');
}

// Function to upload a profile photo
async function uploadProfilePhoto(photoPath) {
    // Read the photo file and convert it to a FileBox object
    const photo = FileBox.fromFile(photoPath);

    // Read the auth result from the file
    const authString = await fs.promises.readFile('auth.json', 'utf8');
    const authResult = JSON.parse(authString);

    // Get the session object from the auth result
    const session = authResult.session;

    // Read the user ID and first and last names from the auth result
    const userId = authResult.user.id;
    const firstName = authResult.user.first_name;
    const lastName = authResult.user.last_name;

    // Create a new TelegramClient object and set the session object
    const client = new TelegramClient({
        apiId,
        apiHash,
        auth: {
            session
        }
    });

    // Set the client's user ID and first and last names
    client.auth.user.id = userId;

    client.auth.user.first_name = firstName;
    client.auth.user.last_name = lastName;

    // Invoke the photos.uploadProfilePhoto method
    try {
        const result = await client.photos.uploadProfilePhoto({
            file: new InputFile({
                buffer: await photo.toBuffer(),
                name: 'profile-photo.jpg',
            }),
        });
        console.log(result); // Prints the result of the uploadProfilePhoto method call
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

async function main() {
    // Authenticate the account
    await authenticate();

    // Call the function to upload the profile photo
    uploadProfilePhoto('./test.png');
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram bot api is only exclusive for bot management, I do not think you can change your profile picture using this api but if you want to change the bot picture write a message to @BotFather typing `/mybots` -> `edit bot` -> `Edit Botpic` and choose a image.